# ¿Cómo hallar el numero mas repetido de una lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo la siguiente lista:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 17, 16, 9, 10, 23, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 4, 20, 4, 22, 23, 24, 4, 4]
```

Quería saber como hallar el numero con mayores repeticiones sin necesidad de utilizar un ciclo ya que esto no lo veo muy practico en especial con listas de longitud muy grande.
Mi idea era utilizar un diccionario cuyos elementos tengan los de la lista y que aquí si revise el numero con mayores repeticiones mediante un for, sin embargo es un proceso que puede ser muy largo pero puede ser efectivo; y la ultima idea era utilizar la función `count` en el un ciclo que revise cada elemento del set de la lista.

¿Existe una forma mas efectiva de resolver este problema? ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Buen día podrías intentarlo con la librería de estadística

```
from statistics import mode
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 17, 16, 9, 10, 23, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 4, 20, 4, 22, 23, 24, 4, 4]
print(mode(x))

# 4
```

Answer (score 10):

Con Python base, tienes algunas alternativas:

```
from collections import Counter

lista = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 17, 16, 9, 10, 23, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 4, 20, 4, 22, 23, 24, 4, 4]

print(Counter(lista).most_common()[0][0])
```

El objeto [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) crea un lista de tuplas con cada elemento y la cantidad de ocurrencias, y el método [`most_common()][2]` de devuelve esa lista ordenada por las ocurrencias de mayor a menor.

Otra forma menos performante pero más compacta de escribir, es:

```
print(max(set(lista), key=lista.count))
```

Aquí generamos un `set` que es el conjunto de los elementos únicos de la lista, y aplicamos un [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) usando un método de toda lista el `count(elemento)` que nos devuelve la cantidad de `elemento` en la lista.

Answer (score 6):

Una posible solución es usar `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 17, 16, 9, 10, 23, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 4, 20, 4, 22, 23, 24, 4, 4]
c = Counter(l)
print(max(c, key=c.get))
```

Output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 3):

Otra opcion es la libreria "scipy".

Ventaja: Cuenta el numero de veces que se repite el número.

Desventaja: Tienes que importar numpy que es otro modulo.

```
from scipy import stats
from numpy import np
```

`a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 17, 16, 9, 10, 23, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 4, 20, 4, 22, 23, 24, 4, 4]`

`moda, count = stats.mode(np.array(a))`

```
print(moda)
[4]
print(count)
[5]
```

Comment: Hola. Es una solución, sí. Aunque creo que importar todo una librería como scipy para hacer algo tan sencillo es un sobretrabajo.

Comment: Para este ejemplo estoy deacuerdo, pero si el proyecto en el que estas trabajando requiere de scipy, creo que es bueno saber que existe este metodo.

Comment: De acuerdo, Miguel.

Answer (score 1):

Hola voy a aportar mi granito de arena con esta respuesta.

```py
from collections import Counter

lista = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 17, 16, 9, 10, 23, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 4, 20, 4, 22, 23, 24, 4, 4]

a=Counter(lista).most_common())
print(a)
```

Esto te devolvera una lista con tuplas dentro que te dira cuantas veces se repite un numero dentro de una lista

```py
#SALIDA:
[(4, 5), (6, 2), (17, 2), (16, 2), (23, 2), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (9, 1), (10, 1), (12, 1), (13, 1), (14, 1), (15, 1), (18, 1), (20, 1), (22, 1), (24, 1)]
```

Por favor si te fue util apoya positivamente la respuesta :)